# Performance difference between named window vs explicit over clause in the select list

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there any performance gain between defining the over clause of an analytic function in the select list vs defining it as a named window?

For example, would there be any performance difference between the two queries down below?
The second query explicitly states that calculated fields 1 and 2 work over the same window.

I am working with BigQuery standard SQL (but also happy to hear about other SQL engines)

Query 1:

```
select
field1, field2, field3,
max(field4) over (partition by field1, field2) as calculated_field_1,
max(field5) over (partition by field1, field2) as calculated_field_2,
max(field6) over (partition by field1) as calculated_field_3,
from my_table
```

Query 2:

```
select
field1, field2, field3,
max(field4) over w as calculated_field_1,
max(field5) over w as calculated_field_2,
max(field6) over (partition by field1) as calculated_field_3,
from my_table
window w as (partition by field1, field2)
```

Comment: no, why should it?

Answer (score -2):

Don't think so there would be any issue. The scanning is same. The memory calculation on window is same in both the queries.